# Rails 3.1 HAML SCSS filter in mailer views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, haml, sass

Is there a filter like the existing :sass-filter for :scss in haml?

Looked out in goolge but didn't found something usefull..

And is there a reason why there is no scss-filer existing (as far as I know)?

Comment: I'm curious, have you tried using the `:sass` filter?  Also, you may want to file this as an issue on the HAML github repo https://github.com/nex3/haml/issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://gist.github.com/1646573

```
# haml_scss_initializer.rb
module Haml::Filters
  module Scss
    include Base
    lazy_require 'sass/plugin'

    def render(text)
      ::Sass::Engine.new(text, ::Sass::Plugin.engine_options.merge(:syntax => :scss)).render
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no filter and I posted an issue on the github page:

https://github.com/nex3/haml/issues/474